Any Info about deploying Next.js apps in Plesk?
It is not possible to deploy next.js applications on plesk servers. (as far as i have tried and read). Does anyone know:
1. How to deploy nextjs applications on plesk?
2. More about a future inegration? When?
All Formus say its not possible. This issue was recognized and quite old too: https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/43919454-support-for-next-js-applications
I also tried this: https://medium.com/@keithchasen/how-to-set-up-your-next-js-app-on-plesk-server-7d8d247a2db2
But seems to be a old workaround, which doesnt work anymore with newer nextjs versions.

Sorry. Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78704668/deploy-next-js-14-on-plesk-server?rq=2

This question is similar to: Deploy Next JS 14 on Plesk server. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
